# (Scala/PlayFramework) Mailgun mail gets truncated when using & in the body

Tags: scala, email, encoding, mailgun, truncated

I'm having troubles to send emails using the & in the body of the html.

This is part of my code

```
val reqHolder: WSRequestHolder = WS.url(url).withAuth("api", apiKey, AuthScheme.BASIC)
  var responseData = Map(
    "from" -> Seq(from),
    "to" -> Seq(emailId),
    "subject" -> Seq(subject),
    "text" -> Seq(content))
  if (!htmlContent.isEmpty) {
    responseData += ("html" -> Seq(htmlContent))
  }
  val response = reqHolder.post(responseData)
```

And for the variable htmlContent something like this

```
htmlContent = "<html>Hi all Im trying mailgun api & testing why mi ampersand cuts my mail</html>"
```

When I send the email, What I get is "Hi all Im trying mailgun api" and the rest is truncated by the &.

Could you give me an advice? I read that can be the encoding, but I don't know how to change the encoding in Scala :(.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the character **"&"**, you can use: **&amp** instead.

Comment: Thats the problem, I cant even use "&amp" because everything after the "&" is cutted off :(

Comment: I found a solution. I was using %26 :D